# Docker volume mount permission strategy different in Centos and MacOS

Tags: docker, centos

I locate the problem a whole day and minimize the problem in the [Github](https://github.com/Eriice/docker-problem).

When I mounted the host file to docker container, and enter to docker container then run `ls -lash` to see the file permission. After mounting, It appears that MacOS's file in container whose permission own by the `user` which is created by Dockerfile, but the Centos's file in container whose permission own by the `root`. It test at the same docker engine version(18.09.2) between MacOS and Centos7.6.

```sh
docker-problem git:(master) ✗ docker run -it -v $PWD:/home/level docker/test bash 
flaskuser@59aeaacf0f4b:/home/level$ ls -lash
total 8.0K
   0 drwxr-xr-x  4 flaskuser flaskgroup  128 Feb 25 19:24 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  1 flaskuser flaskgroup 4.0K Feb 25 19:21 ..
   0 drwxr-xr-x 15 flaskuser flaskgroup  480 Feb 25 19:27 .git
4.0K -rw-r--r--  1 flaskuser flaskgroup  382 Feb 26 11:21 Dockerfile
```

```sh
[root@vultr docker-problem]# docker run -it -v $PWD/:/home/level/ docker/test bash
flaskuser@c843984693a5:/home/level$ ls -lash
total 16K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 3 root      root       4.0K Feb 26 11:29 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 1 flaskuser flaskgroup 4.0K Feb 26 13:14 ..
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 8 root      root       4.0K Feb 26 11:29 .git
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root      root        284 Feb 26 11:29 Dockerfile
```

Is it a bug in docker?

[Test in MacOs](http://img.eriice.com/docker-question-github-mac.png)

[Test in Centos7.6](http://img.eriice.com/docker-question-github-centos.png)

[Github Link](https://github.com/Eriice/docker-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Host volumes will have the ownership and permissions of the host passed into the container. This is done by uid/gid at the filesystem level, not by user name or group name which may vary between the container and host.

Newer versions of Docker for Mac ship with an OSXFS driver to mount the Mac filesystems into the embedded Linux VM with automatic mapping of Linux users to the Mac uid. This is a bit like NFS squashing uid's, but much more dynamic. You can read more about OSXFS at: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/

Comment: Thanks for your help:) I read the document carefully and I can only accept the different between MacOS and Centos in file permission. But it feel weird for docker whose target is to eliminate platform differences.

Comment: @Eriice Docker tries to provide a better UX where possible. On native Linux, bind mounts don't have an option to change the uid mappings from host to container. When you use virtual box, the host to VM filesystem mapping does something similar to this xhyve solution with osxfs.